# UI changes with ObservableObject just after switching tabs

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, combine

I have a `ObservableObject` that I use to update my UI when new data is sent from the server (an a class which contains an array of custom structs).

For some reason, when the data is sent, the `ContentView`'s `body` is called, but the data isn't changed. I even added a `print` statement to check if the data that the array contains is right and it is.

When I try to switch to another tab on my `TabView`, and then switch back to the main view, the UI **does** get updated. Does anybody know why the UI updates just when I switch tabs, although the `body` gets recalled to update the UI when the data changed?

**HomeView**

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var fbData = firebaseData

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            //Home Tab
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(self.fbData.posts.indices, id: \.self) { postIndex in
                        PostView(post: self.$fbData.posts[postIndex])
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("MyPhotoApp", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Camera btn pressed")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                , trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Messages btn pressed")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                )
            } . tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .font(.title)
            })

            Text("Search").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Upload").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Activity").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Profile").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(.black)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

**FirebaseData**:

```
class FirebaseData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    let postsCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")

    init() {
        self.fetchPosts()
    }

    //MARK: Fetch Data
    private func fetchPosts() {
        self.postsCollection.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Error fetching posts: \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else {
                documentSnapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                    if diff.type == .added {
                        let post = self.createPostFromDocument(document: diff.document)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    } else if diff.type == .modified {
                        self.posts = self.posts.map { (post) -> Post in
                            if post.id == diff.document.documentID {
                                return self.createPostFromDocument(document: diff.document)
                            } else {
                                return post
                            }
                        }
                    } else if diff.type == .removed {
                        for index in self.posts.indices {
                            if self.posts[index].id == diff.document.documentID {
                                self.posts.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post more code on how the ObservableObject is linked to the ContentView?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727556/swiftui-why-doesnt-this-binding-change-re-render-the-view/60728102#60728102 and try to understand how SwiftUI knows what to "refresh", "reload" ... etc. The relation between your data and View is done via '@State' or '@ObservedObject' property wrappers. View observes the internal of State or ObservedObject and if see some changes, it reevaluates its body. thats all, there is no miracle behind. The code with lot of .padding, .font .... etc. doesn't help at all.

Comment: @denis_lor Thank you. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: @user3441734 Thank you. I know how the property wrappers work, and the `body` even recalled correctly, but for some reason just the UI itself doesn't change. I've added a bit more information, I'll be happy if you could take a look

Comment: Please post your ObservableObject, it could be a key part of the problem.

Comment: property wrappers are generic mechanism independent from SwiftUI, the implementation of SwiftUI update via State of ObservedObject are still "unknown" and there is a lot of differences between. if View "reevaluates" its body, that means it shows the data which are available and current. How did you checked, that View reevaluates its body? Views body returns just one (maybe really complicated structure), without any running code.

Comment: Put every tab item view into dedicated view struct.

Comment: @zgluis Thank you. I've added the code for the object.

Comment: @user3441734 I've added a breakpoint in the `body` and I can see clearly that it is recalled and has the correct information in the array.

Comment: @Asperi What do you mean? My first tab is linked to a `NavigationView` and my other tabs are linked to a `Text`

Comment: does your TabView have one tabItem only? that is what we see in your code ...

Comment: @user3441734 I have a `TabItem`s, but they are all the same (`TabItem` attached to `Text`, except the first one who is attached to the `NavigationView`) so I didn't post them.

Comment: @user3441734 I've updated my code with the whole two classes/structs. Do you see anything that might cause this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example doesn't help to find the bug. Finally I've got how to demonstrate it. First, do it the "proper way" (copy - paste - try it yourself)

```
import SwiftUI

struct Data: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
}
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Data] = [Data(text: "alfa"), Data(text: "beta")]
 }

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            View1(model: model).tabItem {
                Text("View 1")
            }
            View2(model: model).tabItem {
                Text("View 2")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 1").font(.largeTitle)
            DataView(data: model.data)
            Button(action: {
                self.model.data.append(Data(text: String("ABCDEFGH".shuffled())))
            }) {
                Text("Add random data")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2").font(.largeTitle)
            DataView(data: model.data.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                item.text.count < 4
                }))
                // to distinguish from other DataView !! it seems to be a bug in SwiftUI
                // try to remove it to see the difference
                .id("view2")
            Button(action: {
                self.model.data.append(Data(text: String("ABC".shuffled())))
            }) {
                Text("Add random data")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DataView: View {
    var data: [Data]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(data) { (item) in
                Text(item.text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I works as it should, you can modify the data from each tab, you see refreshed data, etc.

[image]

removing "fixed - user defined" .id modifier, it changes the behaviour dramatically

[image]

**This looks like a serious bug in SwiftUI ...**

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I meant by saying "When I try to switch to another tab on my TabView, and then switch back to the main view, the UI does get updated". I am not trying to pass the information between Tab1 to Tab2. The `posts` array should be just in tab1. But for some reason tab1 doesn't get updated, just when I switch to tab2 (which just has a `text` title, nothing more) and switch back to tab1 the information updates. The code you've posted is like my code but adds another tab. So it doesn't work unfortunately. Any other idea?

Comment: till you publish some minimal "working" example, I am sorry ... what i published above is real bug, which is very hard to identify. I left it here for someone else ...

Comment: please see my updated question with more details and code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60740197/view-doesnt-get-updated-when-using-observableobject/60740602#60740602

Answer (score 0):

I think is SwiftUI bug. I solve this problem like this. 
Instead of rendering your PostView(post: self.$fbData.posts[postIndex])
implement post view inside ForEach.

```
ForEach(self.fbData.posts.indices, id: \.self) { postIndex in
   Text(self.$fbData.posts[postIndex].comment)
   Text(self.$fbData.posts[postIndex].date)
   ....
}
```