# View doesn't get updated when using ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to build an Instagram clone app using SwiftUI.

I'm fetching the data through `Firebase` and trying to achieve a UI update every time the data in the server changes.

For some reason, when I first open the app and fetch the data, the `body` of my view gets called, but the UI doesn't change. I even put a breakpoint and saw the `body` gets called and contains the correct information, it's just the UI which doesn't get updated.

I have a few tabs in my app, and when I switch to another tab (which doesn't contain anything but a `Text` yet), suddenly the UI **does** gets updated.

Please see the gif below:

[image: gif]

Here is my code:

**HomeView**:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var fbData = firebaseData

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            //Home Tab
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    ForEach(self.fbData.posts.indices, id: \.self) { postIndex in
                        PostView(post: self.$fbData.posts[postIndex])
                            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Instagram", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading:
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Camera btn pressed")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                , trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Messages btn pressed")
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                            .font(.title)
                    })
                )
            } . tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "house")
                    .font(.title)
            })

            Text("Search").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Upload").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "plus.app")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Activity").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Profile").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .accentColor(.black)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

**FirebaseData**:

```
let firebaseData = FirebaseData()

class FirebaseData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()

    let postsCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("Posts")

    init() {
        self.fetchPosts()
    }

    //MARK: Fetch Data
    private func fetchPosts() {
        self.postsCollection.addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Error fetching posts: \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            } else {
                documentSnapshot!.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
                    if diff.type == .added {
                        let post = self.createPostFromDocument(document: diff.document)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    } else if diff.type == .modified {
                        self.posts = self.posts.map { (post) -> Post in
                            if post.id == diff.document.documentID {
                                return self.createPostFromDocument(document: diff.document)
                            } else {
                                return post
                            }
                        }
                    } else if diff.type == .removed {
                        for index in self.posts.indices {
                            if self.posts[index].id == diff.document.documentID {
                                self.posts.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func createPostFromDocument(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> Post {
        let data = document.data()

        let id = document.documentID
        let imageUrl = data["imageUrl"] as! String
        let authorUsername = data["authorUsername"] as! String
        let authorProfilePictureUrl = data["authorProfilePictureUrl"] as! String
        let postLocation = data["postLocation"] as! String
        let postDescription = data["postDescription"] as! String
        let numberOfLikes = data["numberOfLikes"] as! Int
        let numberOfComments = data["numberOfComments"] as! Int
        let datePosted = (data["datePosted"] as! Timestamp).dateValue()
        let isLiked = data["isLiked"] as! Bool

        return Post(id: id, imageUrl: imageUrl, authorUsername: authorUsername, authorProfilePictureUrl: authorProfilePictureUrl, postLocation: postLocation, postDescription: postDescription, numberOfLikes: numberOfLikes, numberOfComments: numberOfComments, datePosted: datePosted, isLiked: isLiked)
    }
}
```

If you need me to post more code please let me know.

Update:

**PostView**:

```
struct PostView: View {
    @Binding var post: Post

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            //Info bar
            HStack {
                WebImage(url: URL(string: post.authorProfilePictureUrl))
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .clipShape(Circle())

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                    Text(post.authorUsername).font(.headline)
                    Text(post.postLocation)
                }

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    print("More options pressed")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)

            //Main Image
            WebImage(url: URL(string: post.imageUrl))
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

            //Tools bar
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                Button(action: {
                    self.post.isLiked.toggle()
                    print("Like btn pressed")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: post.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    print("Comments btn pressed")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

                Button(action: {
                    print("Share btn pressed")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    print("Bookmark btn pressed")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
            }.padding(8)

            Text("Liked by \(post.numberOfLikes) users")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)

            Text(post.postDescription)
                .font(.body)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)

            Button(action: {
                print("Show comments btn pressed")
            }, label: {
                Text("See all \(post.numberOfComments) comments")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            }).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())

            Text(post.datePostedString)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
        }
    }
}
```

**Post**:

```
struct Post : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var authorUsername: String
    var authorProfilePictureUrl: String
    var postLocation: String
    var postDescription: String
    var numberOfLikes: Int
    var numberOfComments: Int
    var datePostedString: String

    var isLiked: Bool

    init(id: String, imageUrl: String, authorUsername: String, authorProfilePictureUrl: String, postLocation: String, postDescription : String, numberOfLikes: Int, numberOfComments: Int, datePosted: Date, isLiked: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.authorUsername = authorUsername
        self.authorProfilePictureUrl = authorProfilePictureUrl
        self.postLocation = postLocation
        self.postDescription = postDescription
        self.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes
        self.numberOfComments = numberOfComments

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
        self.datePostedString = dateFormatter.string(from: datePosted)

        self.isLiked = isLiked
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If ever you don't get an answer in a couple of hours or a day, I suggest you make a prototype (a small version of your project), and start from there. Also, perhaps you can consider sharing the tutorial link (if there's any), for us to download the sample complete project to help you further. 

*Just in case needed, I asked on meta so about asking for a sample project from OP. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379198/asking-for-a-sample-project-from-op*

Comment: @Glenn Thank you. Currently my project is very small so instead of uploading a file I've added 2 more code sections to my question. Please take a look, you can even paste it to Xcode because it's all code needed

Comment: @Glenn I did. Please see the section above `Post`

Comment: Thanks. Will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when the app starts your array is empty, and the ScrollView stops updating, you can replace it for a VStack and it will work (just for testing).

The solution is to wrap the `ForEach`(or the ScrollView) with a condition, like this:

```
if (fbData.posts.count > 0) {
    ForEach(self.fbData.posts.indices, id: \.self) { postIndex in
        PostView(post: self.$fbData.posts[postIndex])
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you please explain a bit more about this solution? Isn't `ScrollView` gets updated just like a `VStack`? What was the problem? Thanks again!