# Why does TabView shows blank screen if two views are the same?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a TabView in my app that is meant to display four screens. Two are similar but have different data sources. If I click on the first tab (EventsScreen), and then the third tab (MyBagScreen) everything works fine. If I click on the first tab (EventsScreen) and then the second tab (EventsScreen), it just loads a blank screen (i presume it is only loading the background). They are two different objects, so why does this not work?

AppView.swift

```
struct AppView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            EventsScreen().environmentObject(EventsViewModel(repo: IncentivesRespository()))
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Barter")
                    Image("icon_barter")
            }
            EventsScreen().environmentObject(EventsViewModel(repo: OpportunityRepository()))
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Earn")
                    Image("icon_earn")
            }
            MyBagScreen().environmentObject(MyBagViewModel())
                .tabItem{
                    Text("My Bag")
                    Image("icon_bag")
            }
            AccountScreen().environmentObject(AccountViewModel())
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Account")
                    Image("icon_account")

            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .black
        })
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

EventsScreen

```
struct EventsScreen: View {

    @EnvironmentObject
    var viewModel: EventsViewModel

    let calendarManager = RKManager(calendar: Calendar.current, minimumDate: Date(), maximumDate: Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*90), mode: 1)

    @State
    var currentPage: Int = 0
    @State
    private var searchTerm : String = ""

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List {
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    EventViewController(controllers: self.viewModel.featureEventControllers, currentPage: self.$currentPage)
                    VStack {
                        SearchBar(text: self.$searchTerm)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16))
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Chip(text: "Dates", action:  {
                                self.viewModel.showDateSelection.toggle()
                            })
                                .sheet(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showDateSelection, onDismiss: {
                                    self.viewModel.onDatesSelected(startDate: self.calendarManager.startDate, endDate: self.calendarManager.endDate)
                                }, content: {
                                    RKViewController(isPresented: self.$viewModel.showDateSelection, rkManager: self.calendarManager)
                                })
                            Chip(text:"Type", action: {
                                self.viewModel.showTypeSelection.toggle()
                            })
                            Chip(text: "Points", action: {
                                self.viewModel.showPointsSelection.toggle()
                            })
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    .frame(height: 600)
                ForEach(self.viewModel.eventSections.indices) { id in
                    EventSectionView(eventSection: self.viewModel.eventSections[id])
                }
                .listRowBackground(Color.black)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Events"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            if self.viewModel.showPointsSelection {
                EventsPointsRangeBottomSheet(isOpen: self.$viewModel.showPointsSelection, selectedRange: self.$viewModel.selectedRange, range: 0.0...self.viewModel.maxPoints, action: {
                    self.viewModel.onPointsSelected()
                })

            }
            if self.viewModel.showTypeSelection {
                TypeBottomSheet(categories: self.viewModel.allCategories, isOpen: self.$viewModel.showTypeSelection, selectedCategoryUuids: self.$viewModel.selectedCategoryUuids, action: {
                    self.viewModel.onTypesSelected()
                })
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of EventsScreen.. I am using my View twice aswell in a Navigation View and it is working fine

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738953/3441734

Comment: @user3441734 I dont understand how that question is relevant.

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin Can you try to change the order of the screens? (swap the repositories)
And check if you're having the same behavior, it may be due to missing data from one of the repositories

Answer (score 4):

Your code snapshot is not testable, so just an idea - you have to test it itself.

So, assuming that your environment object for second view is correct, try to to make those to views really unique by using `.id` modifier, like below

```swift
TabView {
    EventsScreen().environmentObject(EventsViewModel(repo: IncentivesRespository()))
        .id(1)                    // << here !!
        .tabItem {
            Text("Barter")
            Image("icon_barter")
    }
    EventsScreen().environmentObject(EventsViewModel(repo: OpportunityRepository()))
        .id(2)                    // << here !!
        .tabItem {
            Text("Earn")
            Image("icon_earn")
    }
    ...
```

**Note:** I see usage `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in `AppView` - if it means you are going to include `TabView` into `NavigationView`, then **don't do that** - you won't have it work. TabView is designed to be **root view only**. If you need navigation place it *inside* tabs.

Comment: If I number the id's starting at 1 as you have in your solution, this will fix the issue, but then causes a bug where tabItems are no longer evenly spaced and clicking on the third tabitem opens the whole AppView inside of it (really weird)... If I number the id's starting at 0, then this has no effect..

Comment: @AdrianLeRoyDevezin, I've tried to replicate your situation with two simple same views (and other different) having different environment objects in TabView and did not observe any unexpected behaviour (used Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4), either w/ or w/o .id. So it is not about TabView and not about same tab items. Look in different code logic (maybe it is what I told about NavigationView - TabView must be root). That's it.

Comment: How I could I navigate to a TabView then? Such as moving from a login screen, to the home screen of an application/

Comment: Navigating from Login screen to other screen is really out of topic. There are a lot of examples here on SO how to do that w/o NavigationView, like replacement, transitions, etc. I experimenting hard to make TabView work inside NavigationView, but it fails (sooner or later), because TabView, using internally UITabBarController is designed to be root.